# Programmatically set background tinting of AppCompatCheckBox

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I want to tint the background of a CheckBox at runtime. It cannot be done statically using theming. I can theme the text & checkbox drawable without any issues.

I expected this to work:

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
    };
    int[] backgroundColors = new int[] {
            backgroundColor,
            backgroundColor,
            backgroundColor,
            backgroundColor
    };
    ColorStateList backgroundColorStateList = new ColorStateList(getStates(), backgroundColors);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        checkbox.setBackgroundTintList(backgroundColorStateList);
    }
```

But this does exactly nothing to the background, even on a Marshmallow device.

Theming just about anything in Android dynamically is utterly horrible and absurdly time-consuming. Why is the above code not working, and where is setSupportBackgroundTintList() ?

At the moment I'm using this, but it removes the ripple and shadowing:

```
    checkbox.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
```

Is there really no way to tint a Checkbox background, even using AppCompat?